# Export to excel from Gridview with color codes

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, export-to-excel

I'm using color code based on some percentage logic in the `GridView`. But while exporting to `Excel` I dont know how to maintain this color code in the `Excel`. Please guide

Below is the code for `RowDataBound`

```
protected void Grd_QADetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var dataRowView = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            DataRow row = dataRowView.Row;

            var Current = (row["Current Month Percentage"] as double?) ?? null;

            double? Yellow = (double?)Convert.ToDouble(row["Yellow"]);
            double? Green = (double?)Convert.ToDouble(row["Green"]);

            if (Current != null)
            {
                if (Current >= Green)
                    e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = Color.Green;

                if (Current >= Yellow && Current < Green)
                    e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                if (Current < Yellow)
                    e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = Color.Red;
            }               
        }
    }
```

Below is the code for `Export to Excel`

```
private void ExportthroughWeb(DataTable dt, string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string filename = FileName + ".xls";

                using (System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
                {
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
                    DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
                    dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                    dgGrid.DataBind();

                    //Get the HTML for the control.
                    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                    //Write the HTML back to the browser.

                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                    this.EnableViewState = false;

                    Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">" + Environment.NewLine);
                    Response.Write(tw.ToString());

                    Response.Write("</body>");
                    Response.Write("</html>");

                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Raghu..are you not getting the color codes while exporting to excel, is RowDataBound getting called? Can you give furthur info..

Comment: @AvinashKothamasu `Gridview` shows the color codes. But in `Excel` after `Export` I want to maintain these color logic. I dont know how to achieve it...

Comment: @Raghu..currently you are getting a grid with no colors using above colors right?

Comment: I'm getting colors in `ASP.NET GridView`... I dont have problem with that.. I've a button which calls function `ExportthroughWeb()` which exports the `DataTable` `dt` values to `Excel` where I need these color code..

Comment: While exporting , are you losing colors?

Comment: thats correct. I needed colors in `Excel` which I've defined in `RowDataBound`

Comment: @Raghu..I tested the code i posted as answer below..its working fine now..its exporting with colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach an event handler for `RowDataBound`

**Please modify your code as follows:**

```
private void ExportthroughWeb(DataTable dt, string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string filename = FileName + ".xls";

                using (System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
                {
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
                    GridView dgGrid = new GridView();
                    dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                    dgGrid.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(Grd_QADetails_RowDataBound);
                    dgGrid.DataBind();

                    //Get the HTML for the control.
                    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                    //Write the HTML back to the browser.

                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                    this.EnableViewState = false;

                    Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">" + Environment.NewLine);
                    Response.Write(tw.ToString());

                    Response.Write("</body>");
                    Response.Write("</html>");

                    Response.End();
                }
            }
```

Hope this helps..

**My Tested Example:** Update

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="webapp1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdDetails" OnRowDataBound="Grd_QADetails_RowDataBound">

    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button  runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="ExportToGrid"/>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;

namespace webapp1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        DataTable dtDetails = new DataTable();


        protected void Grd_QADetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                var dataRowView = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
                DataRow row = dataRowView.Row;

                var Current = (row["Dosage"] as int?) ?? null;


                if (Current != null)
                {
                    if (Current >= 1 && Current < 10)
                        e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Green;

                    else if (Current >= 10 && Current < 20)
                        e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                    else
                        e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            dtDetails.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            dtDetails.Columns.Add("Drug Suggested", typeof(string));
            dtDetails.Columns.Add("Patient Name", typeof(string));
            dtDetails.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dtDetails.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dtDetails.Columns.Add("Payment Mode", typeof(string));
            dtDetails.Columns.Add("Appointment Status", typeof(string));
            dtDetails.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));

            dtDetails.Rows.Add(1, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(2, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(3, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(4, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(5, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");

            dtDetails.Rows.Add(6, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(7, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(8, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(9, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(10, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");

            dtDetails.Rows.Add(11, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(12, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(13, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(14, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(15, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");

            dtDetails.Rows.Add(16, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(17, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(18, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(19, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(20, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");

            dtDetails.Rows.Add(21, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(22, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(23, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(24, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
            dtDetails.Rows.Add(25, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                grdDetails.DataSource = dtDetails;
                grdDetails.DataBind();
            }

        }

        protected void ExportToGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ExportToGrid(dtDetails);
        }

        private void ExportToGrid(DataTable dt)
        {

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string filename = "Avinash" + ".xls";

                using (System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
                {
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
                    GridView dgGrid = new GridView();
                    dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                    dgGrid.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(Grd_QADetails_RowDataBound);
                    dgGrid.DataBind();

                    //Get the HTML for the control.
                    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                    //Write the HTML back to the browser.

                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                    this.EnableViewState = false;

                    Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">" + Environment.NewLine);
                    Response.Write(tw.ToString());

                    Response.Write("</body>");
                    Response.Write("</html>");

                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }

    }![enter image description here][1]
}
```

[image]

Comment: I get error during compile saying 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'RowDataBound' and no extension method 'RowDataBound' accepting a first argument'

Comment: Yes, I did try using `GridView` even before your reply. But i'm not getting any values in Excel when I change it to Gridview.. it's all blank!

Comment: @Raghu..Above is the sample example..i have tested with..i am not sure what is the problem with your code.but this is the one that worked out for me..as you can see in above picture

Comment: I tried again with fresh webpage but again it goes blank. Though I get an error message 'Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack' which I've handled using catch     (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException lException)
            {
                string str = lException.Message;
            }

Comment: @Raghu..Have you tried debugging..at which line you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link you will find helpful. Just Change your condition of color accordingly.
http://gridview-excel.blogspot.in/2011/12/gridview-to-excel-in-aspnetc.html